# How to inverse NSScrollView scrolling direction?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I have NSScrollView which i transform by CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), then it started scrolling in wrong direction, now i need to scroll to opposite direction according Y axe

**Update:**

found solution by subclassing NSScrollView:

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    int scrollingDeltaY = -[theEvent deltaY];
    CGEventRef cgEvent = CGEventCreateCopy(theEvent.CGEvent);

    CGEventSetIntegerValueField(cgEvent, kCGScrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1, scrollingDeltaY);

    NSEvent *newEvent = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:cgEvent];
    CFRelease(cgEvent);

    [super scrollWheel:newEvent];
}
```

Comment: Why do you transform the scroll view?

Comment: @Willeke For messenger, you turn it upside down and it allows to show last message instantly but not to scroll it programmatically every time to bottom position to show last message

Comment: Flip the scroll view?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, using .layer.sublayerTransform

Comment: I mean overriding `isFlipped`.

Comment: @Willeke and is it supposed to work? it says in documentation: "A Boolean value indicating whether the view uses a flipped coordinate system.", are you sure it flips upside down view? for me it has no effect